# Does detect faces need google play store?

Tags: google-mlkit

i used the Detect faces with ML Kit on Android.i can get the result of detection, but the console printed the warning that
"W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: com.example.mlkitfacedemo requires the Google Play Store, but it is missing.
W/GoogleApiManager: The service for com.google.android.gms.common.internal.service.zap is not available: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_INVALID, resolution=null, message=null}"

thanks for your help.

this is my whole code

```
// MainActivity2.java
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView beforeIV, afterIV;

    int imageMaxWidth;
    int imageMaxHeight;

    Bitmap resizedBitmap;
    TextView tv;


    private static final int[] COLORS = {
            Color.TRANSPARENT,
            Color.BLUE,
            Color.RED,
            Color.YELLOW,
            Color.GREEN,
            Color.MAGENTA,
            Color.BLUE,
            Color.RED,
            Color.RED,
            Color.BLUE,
            Color.GRAY,
            Color.LTGRAY,
            Color.YELLOW,
            Color.BLUE,
            Color.CYAN,
            Color.GREEN
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        beforeIV = findViewById(R.id.before);
//        beforeIV.setImageResource(R.drawable.grapefruit);
        afterIV = findViewById(R.id.after);



        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.grapefruit);

        tv = findViewById(R.id.textView);

        View rootView = findViewById(R.id.root);
        rootView.getViewTreeObserver()
                .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                        new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                                rootView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                                imageMaxWidth = rootView.getWidth();
                                imageMaxHeight = rootView.getHeight() / 2;
                                System.out.println("rootView Size: " + rootView.getWidth() + ", " + rootView.getHeight());

                                float scaleFactor =
                                        max(
                                                (float) bitmap.getWidth() / (float) imageMaxWidth,
                                                (float) bitmap.getHeight() / (float) imageMaxHeight);

                                resizedBitmap =
                                        Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
                                                bitmap,
                                                (int) (bitmap.getWidth() / scaleFactor),
                                                (int) (bitmap.getHeight() / scaleFactor),
                                                true);

                                beforeIV.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap);
                                detect();
                            }
                        });
    }

    private void detect() {
        // 准备检测器
        // High-accuracy landmark detection and face classification
        FaceDetectorOptions highAccuracyOpts =
                new FaceDetectorOptions.Builder()
                        .setPerformanceMode(FaceDetectorOptions.PERFORMANCE_MODE_ACCURATE)
                        .setLandmarkMode(FaceDetectorOptions.LANDMARK_MODE_ALL)
                        .setClassificationMode(FaceDetectorOptions.CLASSIFICATION_MODE_ALL)
                        .setContourMode(FaceDetectorOptions.CONTOUR_MODE_ALL)
                        .build();

        // Real-time contour detection
        FaceDetectorOptions realTimeOpts =
                new FaceDetectorOptions.Builder()
                        .setContourMode(FaceDetectorOptions.CONTOUR_MODE_ALL)
                        .build();


        InputImage image = InputImage.fromBitmap(resizedBitmap, 0);

        FaceDetector detector = FaceDetection.getClient(highAccuracyOpts);
        // Or use the default options:
        // FaceDetector detector = FaceDetection.getClient();

        Task<List<Face>> result =
                detector.process(image)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(
                                new OnSuccessListener<List<Face>>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(List<Face> faces) {
                                        // Task completed successfully
                                        // ...
                                        System.out.println("检测成功");
                                        Face face = faces.get(0);
                                        List<FaceLandmark> allLandmarks = face.getAllLandmarks();
                                        for (int i = 0; i < allLandmarks.size(); i++) {
                                            System.out.println(allLandmarks.get(i).getPosition().x);
                                            System.out.println(allLandmarks.get(i).getPosition().y);
                                        }
                                        Rect bounds = face.getBoundingBox();
                                        Paint boxPaint = new Paint();
                                        boxPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
                                        boxPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
                                        boxPaint.setStrokeWidth(5.f);
                                        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(resizedBitmap);
                                        canvas.drawRect(bounds, boxPaint);

                                        // getAllContours - 面部133个点
                                        Paint pathPaint = new Paint();
                                        pathPaint.setStrokeWidth(5.f);
                                        pathPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
                                        List<FaceContour> allContours = face.getAllContours();
                                        System.out.println("allContours size: " + allContours.size());
                                        int sum = 0;
                                        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                                        for (int i = 0; i < allContours.size(); i++) {
                                            String string = "allContours[" + i + "]: " + allContours.get(i).getPoints().size();
                                            System.out.println("allContours[" + i + "]: " + allContours.get(i).getPoints().size());
                                            sum += allContours.get(i).getPoints().size();
                                            builder.append(string);
                                            pathPaint.setColor(COLORS[i]);
                                            List<PointF> points = allContours.get(i).getPoints();
                                            float bx = points.get(0).x;
                                            float by = points.get(0).y;
                                            for (int j = 0; j < points.size(); j++) {
                                                float cx = points.get(j).x;
                                                float cy = points.get(j).y;
                                                String str = "points[" + j + "]: (" + cx + ", " + cy + "), ";
                                                builder.append(str);
                                                canvas.drawLine(bx, by, cx, cy, pathPaint);
                                                bx = cx;
                                                by = cy;
                                            }
                                            builder.append("\n");
                                        }
                                        System.out.println("sum: " + sum);
                                        tv.setText(builder.toString());
                                        runOnUiThread(() -> {
                                            afterIV.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap);
                                        });
                                    }
                                })
                        .addOnFailureListener(
                                new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                        // Task failed with an exception
                                        // ...
                                        System.out.println("检测失败");
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                });
    }
}
```

```
// activity_main2.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity2">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/before"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/after"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/before"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/before"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/before"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/before"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/before"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```
// in build.gradle
dependencies {

    ...
    
    // google mlkit face detection
    implementation 'com.google.mlkit:face-detection:16.1.5'
    
    ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

com.google.mlkit:face-detection is the bundled version which doesn't require Google Play Services or Google Play Store.
https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/face-detection/android

Might be this warning from other parts in your demo? Can you also share your AndroidManifest.xml?